# Webview - passing values from javascript to java

Tags: java, android

I have a webview in android where its height must be resized.
In the webview I'm showing only one div!
The problem is that I need to get its height (with javascript) and pass that value to the android app.After that I`ll set the height of the webview dynamically.

Tried that with different methods but ...

Is there a simple method for this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using JavaScriptInterface.

In your activity:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJSInterface(context), "myInterface");
```

Your class for Interface:

```
public class MyJSInterface {
    Context context;
    MyJSInterface(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void passHeight(int height){
        //Your code
    }
}
```

Call it from javascript as

```
myJSInterface.passHeight(230); //Here 230 will be replaced by your variable
```

Hope this helps.